# onClick function is not working as expected in React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, onclick, handler

So i have this component `ExpenseItem`. Im trying to use `onClick` on the sub component `Card`. First i tried putting an arrow function inside the brackets, but it **didn't work**. Then i initialized the arrow function outside the return and tried to put the function inside the **onClick brackets**, but im not sure why its still **not working**. Here's the code:

```
import React from 'react';
import '../styles/ExpenseItem.css';
import ExpenseDate from './ExpenseDate';
import Card from '../Card.jsx';

const ExpenseItem = (props) => {
  
    const clickHandler = () => alert('im working');

    return (

        <Card className='expense-item' onClick={clickHandler}>
            <div>
                <ExpenseDate date={props.date} />
            </div>
            <div className='expense-item__description'>
                <div className='expense-item__descbox'>
                    <h2>{props.title}</h2>
                    <span>{props.type}</span>
                </div>
                <div className='expense-item__price'>{props.amount}</div>
            </div>
        </Card>
    )
};

export default ExpenseItem;
```

Thanks.

Comment: can you add the `Card` component ?

Comment: @Nokwiw here it is: 
`
import './styles/Card.css';

const Card = (props) => {
    const classes = `card ${props.className}`;
    return <div className={classes}>{props.children}</div>
};

export default Card;

`

Comment: @AthosFranco well where...

Comment: You are missing a closing tag for `div` below `ExpenseDate`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also need to implement `onClick` on your `Card` component.

you can do something like below to your `Card`:

```
const Card = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className="card" {...props}>{props.children}</div>
  );
}
```

OR

```
const Card = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className="card" onClick={props.onClick}>{props.children}</div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

do that in your `Card` component :

```
    const Card = (props) => {
     const classes = card ${props.className};
     return <div className={classes} onClick={props.onClick}>{props.children}</div> 
};

   export default Card;
```